# How to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to user on MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with granting privileges to mysql user.

I tried following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'userpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But it returns following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysun'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I know that this is indicating to wrong password, but I am sure that my password is correct, now what can be the issue, Please suggest if anybody knows the solution to this problem.

Update :

> mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
>    +------------------------------------------------+ 
>    Grants for mysun@localhost
>    +------------------------------------------------+ 
>    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mysun'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
>    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx_xxxxx`.* TO 'mysun'@'localhost'
>    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx_xxxxxxxx`.* TO 'mysun'@'localhost'
>    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx_xxxxxxxxx`.* TO 'mysun'@'localhost'
>    +------------------------------------------------+
>    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Run `SHOW ALL PRIVILEGES for 'mysun'@'localhost'` and copy that result.

Comment: And I would opine that it's very bad practise to give any user *ALL* privileges. You're setting yourself up to be breached.

Comment: Your current account does not have permission to run the GRANT command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: **Does not compute** Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342791) Says you cannot connect to the database, and now you are suggesting that you are connected and getting this error? Which one is it??

Comment: maybe he runs more then one MySQL server?  @RiggsFolly but who knows

Comment: @RiggsFolly So one of the developers suggested in a comment to GRANT permission in my previous question, so when I ran command to grant permisson I am getting this error thats why I posted it here.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Now I am getting this error : ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Are you using a SuperUser account like `root` or a low level user account

Comment: ....... Obviously not a SuperUsers :)

Comment: o yes sorry wrong syntax `SHOW ALL PRIVILEGES for 'mysun'@'localhost'` should be `SHOW GRANTS FOR  'mysun'@'localhost'` or more easy `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();`

Comment: @AndroidDev it sounds like you're fumbling in the dark. Maybe it would be more constructive to go and dig out some online tutorials and read the [**MySQL Documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for a day before returning to your issue with new knowledge `:-)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have updated the question with SHOW GRANTS result.

Comment: Do not replace code with an image. Code can be formatted. An image can not.